# Can I turn logging off in Restlet framework?

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

I have some code that is using the Restlet framework. It is writing an ERROR into my log4j log file:

```
2012-05-30 12:16:42,169 3278917 ERROR [STDERR] (Thread-97:) 30-May-2012 12:16:42 org.restlet.engine.http.connector.HttpClientHelper start
INFO: Starting the default HTTP client
```

Is there any way I can turn this logging off? I see there is a `Client.getLogger()`, but I can't see a way to use that to turn logging off.

Answer (score 3):

You can rely on regular Java logging configuration (java.util.logging). Restlet Framework provides a simple way to adjust those properties, programmatically. Call for example:

```
org.restlet.engine.Engine.setLogLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: Hi Jerome. org.restlet.engine.Engine doesn't have a setLogLevel method.

Comment: and this has no effect either: `client.getLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);`. It still prints to the log as soon as this is called `Response response = client.handle(request);`.

Comment: Anyone got any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi it maybe a little late but for me the following code did it:

```
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource();
resource.getLogger().setLevel(Level.WARNING); //<-- important
```

I left out the resource configuration and exectution because they are not important;-)